# Java Websocket onmessage null

Tags: java, java-ee, websocket

Здравствуйте. Почему в следующем коде переменная _message в методе Message получает null?

```
    @OnOpen
public void OpenSession(Session session, EndpointConfig enpoint) throws IOException, EncodeException
{
    this._session = session;
}

public void OutputJsonMessage(JsonObject message) throws IOException, EncodeException
{

    this._message = message;
}

@OnMessage
public void Message(Reader message)
{
    ImageDecoder imgdecoder = new ImageDecoder();
    try{

        if(imgdecoder.Encode(message) == true)
        {
            try{
                if(this._message != null)
                {
                    this._session.getBasicRemote().sendObject(this._message);
                } else{

                    System.out.println("Message Variable is Null");
                }
        } catch(IOException | EncodeException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        } else{
            return;
        }
    } catch(IOException | EncodeException ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Пробовал через др. метод но this.session выбрасывает nullException.

Comment: какая то java у вас обШАРПанная...

Comment: дебагом приложение подымали? Скорей всего объект json принимается null.

Comment: Это известная проблема, назовите настоящую причину.

Comment: @bench_doos this.message принимает Null когда переменная this.message находится в методе наследованный от OnMessage или OnOpen

Comment: @Roman C не отправляется данные т.е данные приходит в метод  OutputJsonMessage но при отправке через метод Message _message получает null.

Comment: А какое было значение до отправки?

Comment: @RomanC {"Confidence:" 99, "Uncompared:" 0}

Comment: Данные могут не отправляться по другой причине.